# How to insert records using select statement?

Tags: postgresql, select, insert, bulk-insert

Hi I am working on one project, here what I am trying is, I want to insert records what I get using select statements into temp table. but it is giving error to me, can any one help me to solve this ?

ERROR:  relation "temp_mytbl" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01

following is my query

```
truncate table temp_mytbl;
create temporary table temp_mytbl as
select iex_id,dte,agent_name,schd_total
FROM source_xrx_iex6_sandy_1.iex6_agent_adh_sum  limit 0;

 insert into temp_mytbl
select iex_id,dte,agent_name,schd_total
FROM source_xrx_iex6_sandy_1.iex6_agent_adh_sum 
group by iex_id,dte,agent_name,schd_total;

SELECT i.dte,
    idm.empl_id,
    1 AS entity_id,
    sum(i.schd_total) AS s_schdhours
   FROM temp_mytbl i
     JOIN source_odw_usac.t_incontact_agentstatelog a ON a.winid = i.iex_id::text
     JOIN reporting_prod.idm_dte idm ON idm.src_id = a.agent_no AND idm.src_type_id = 618 AND soar_date(a.calendar_date_key) >= idm.start_dte AND soar_date(a.calendar_date_key) <= COALESCE(idm.end_dte, now()::date)
  GROUP BY i.dte, idm.empl_id limit 100;
```

Comment: *but it is giving error to me* What statement generates the error? What is the error message generated by DB server precisely? Add DDLs for all 3 tables used into the question text.

Comment: syntax error near select

Comment: Please post the whole error message without any edition storing linebreaks, spaces counts and so on...

Comment: The real question is: why the temp table to begin with?  You could simply replace `from temp_mytbl i` with `from (select iex_id, FROM source.... ) i` and get rid of the unnecessary overhead of writing the data first.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `COALESCE(idm.end_dte, now()::date)` can be simplified to  `COALESCE(idm.end_dte, current_date)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please see edited question

Comment: @Akina please see edited question

Comment: This error message means that the table/view `temp_mytbl` not exists in your database. So you must create it before use.

Comment: @Akina I have created table, yet giving same error. can you help

Comment: Remove TRUNCATE statement. And use one CREATE TABLE .. SELECT instead of 2 separate queries. PS. Your intermediate static table seems to be excess - use CTE.

Comment: @Akina I did not get you, can you edit with query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH temp_mytbl AS ( -- without aggregation in output expression / HAVING clause
                     -- GROUP BY must be replaced with DISTINCT
                     -- which is less expensive
                     SELECT DISTINCT iex_id, dte, agent_name, schd_total
                     FROM source_xrx_iex6_sandy_1.iex6_agent_adh_sum 
                   )
SELECT i.dte, idm.empl_id, 1 AS entity_id, SUM(i.schd_total) AS s_schdhours
FROM temp_mytbl i
JOIN source_odw_usac.t_incontact_agentstatelog a ON a.winid = i.iex_id::text
JOIN reporting_prod.idm_dte idm ON idm.src_id = a.agent_no 
                               AND idm.src_type_id = 618 
                               AND soar_date(a.calendar_date_key) >= idm.start_dte 
                               AND soar_date(a.calendar_date_key) <= COALESCE(idm.end_dte, now()::date)
GROUP BY i.dte, idm.empl_id /* , entity_id */ 
-- LIMIT without ORDER BY makes no sense
ORDER BY i.dte /* or another sorting expression */
LIMIT 100;
```

or the same in subquery form

```
SELECT i.dte, idm.empl_id, 1 AS entity_id, SUM(i.schd_total) AS s_schdhours
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT iex_id, dte, agent_name, schd_total
       FROM source_xrx_iex6_sandy_1.iex6_agent_adh_sum 
     ) i
JOIN source_odw_usac.t_incontact_agentstatelog a ON a.winid = i.iex_id::text
JOIN reporting_prod.idm_dte idm ON idm.src_id = a.agent_no 
                               AND idm.src_type_id = 618 
                               AND soar_date(a.calendar_date_key) >= idm.start_dte 
                               AND soar_date(a.calendar_date_key) <= COALESCE(idm.end_dte, now()::date)
GROUP BY i.dte, idm.empl_id 
ORDER BY i.dte
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: hi akina, I appriciate your effort for this, it is helpful. this query is working fine. but using distinct it gives data for same id. what I was working to get the data in temp table, can you help me with group by ?

Comment: can you help me with this issue https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270764/wrong-output-getting-from-query

Answer (score -1):

```
create table #temp_mytbl (
 iex_id int,
 dte int,
 agent_name varchar(10),
 schd_total float
 )

 insert into #temp_mytbl
select iex_id,dte,agent_name,schd_total
FROM source_xrx_iex6_sandy_1.iex6_agent_adh_sum 
group by iex_id,dte,agent_name,schd_total;

SELECT i.dte,
    idm.empl_id,
    1 AS entity_id,
    sum(i.schd_total) AS s_schdhours
   FROM #temp_mytbl i
     JOIN source_odw_usac.t_incontact_agentstatelog a ON a.winid = i.iex_id::text
     JOIN reporting_prod.idm_dte idm ON idm.src_id = a.agent_no AND idm.src_type_id = 618 AND soar_date(a.calendar_date_key) >= idm.start_dte AND soar_date(a.calendar_date_key) <= COALESCE(idm.end_dte, now()::date)
  GROUP BY i.dte, idm.empl_id limit 100;


  DROP TABLE #temp_mytbl
```

Comment: `#temp_mytbl ` is an invalid identifier in Postgres (and standard SQL)