# Wrong output getting from query

Tags: postgresql

Hi I have written this query as per my project requirement. But it is generating wrong output.

```
select (to_char((33)/nullif((17400/3600),0),'FM99,999,999'))::character varying as userdatas
```

currently it is generating 8 as output. But according to calculation it is different,

= 33/(17400/3600)

= 33/(4.8333333333333)

= 33/4.8333333333333

= 6.8275862068966

It should display 7

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the cast to `::character varying` is completely useless

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not **quite** useless m'lud! Check out [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ca89630e39e5db9cbab597a78b0ced74) - the bottom two fiddles - one gives a result of type `TEXT` and the other a `VARCHAR` type - a fine distinction indeed, but a distinction nonetheless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your numbers are integers, so the whole expression is done using integer division. You need to either provide numeric constant, e.g. using `3600.0` or cast at least one number to `numeric`

```
select 33/(17400/3600::numeric);
```

returns 6.8276, when applying to_char() it's correctly rounded to 7:

```
select to_char(33/(17400/3600::numeric),'FM99,999,999')
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f8a944d9390c08837b6b9c47b83ce1c9)

Comment: Or tack `.0` on the end of those integers?

Comment: Could you explain why putting `33.0` doesn't work correctly whereas putting `3600.0` does work (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ca89630e39e5db9cbab597a78b0ced74)) - I find that puzzling?

Comment: @RickJames - the explicit typecast is **much** more legible and clearer than the adding a `.0` fix - gotta love PostgreSQL's `::TYPE` syntax for `CAST`s!

Comment: @Vérace - I would expect `33.0/(17400/3600)` to do `(17400/3600)` in integer, then switch to float to do the rest.  `33.0/(17400.0/3600.0)` is what I was suggesting.  It's a common technique in many (not all) languages.

Comment: @RickJames - thanks so much for that explanation - really clarified the whole area for me (which I thought that I had understood!). This [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6186d2a49a6478d64fc1d0318540d2ae) shows the various permuations that are possible - evaluation order being critical - though a belt and braces approach is obviously best with `.0` being tacked on everywhere - having `::NUMERIC` everywhere would be a bit clumsy - thanks again!

Comment: @Vérace - When specifying a computer language (not just SQL), a big stumbling block is what to do with "divide".  For floats, it is obvious.  But for integers, would it be a truncated divide that return an integer?  Or some the args auto-convert to float?  Then, if "/" does not do an integer divide, what should?  Some use `DIV` as an operator.  And `MOD` or `%` for the matching "remainder".  And, for optimizing, can the parens be ignored?  Generally, no; the parens must be honored for what to do first.  And what about an operation that involves one int an d one float?  Etc.